# Does Office 365 contain Microsoft.Office COM DLLs?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, com, ms-office, office365

On my new laptop, I am unable to add a reference to `Microsoft.Office.Core` etc. although an activated version of Office 365 is installed (formerly, I had used Office 2016). Visual Studio Reference Manager simply does not show any matching COM entry.

Does Office 365 not include this feature, or do I have to adjust anything myself?

**Edit:** On my laptop, Office was preinstalled. In modern settings app "Apps & Features" it is listed as "Microsoft Office Desktop Apps", but since I cannot find this entry in classic Control Panel's "Programs and Features", I have to assume it is an UWP app.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you use an MSI installer or Click2Run for installing Office on the machine?

Comment: It was preinstalled on my laptop. In modern settings app "Apps & Features" it is listed as "Microsoft Office Desktop Apps", but since I cannot find this entry in classic Control Panel's "Programs and Features", I have to assume it is an UWP app.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `Office .NET Programmability Support` was chosen in the installer.

Comment: I do not have any installer; Office has been preinstalled on my laptop. modern settings app "Apps & Features" it is named "Microsoft Office Desktop Apps", but it has got only an uninstall button. I cannot find Office in classic Control Panel's "Programs and Features", so it must be an UWP app.

Comment: You need to download MSI based installer for Office and use it.

Comment: So you mean the preinstalled UWP version does not suffice?